# resume() does not work if playback was paused for some time in lockscreen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, avfoundation

The AVPlayer notify AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeNotification when playing the stream . i use the below code and print the error details :

```
NSError *error = notification.userInfo[AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeErrorKey];
NSLog(@"itemFailedToPlayMPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError=%@" ,error);
```

Error details:

```
1. Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11853 "Stream has no valid 
alternates" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=This data is damaged, incomplete,
 or incompatible., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Parse, 
NSDebugDescription=Stream has no valid alternates, NSUnderlyingError=0x155aa070 
{Error Domain=CoreMediaErrorDomain Code=-12880 "Can not proceed after removing 
variant" UserInfo={NSDescription=Can not proceed after removing variant}}}

2. Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the 
server." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x137d39380 {Error 
Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo=
{NSErrorPeerAddressKey={length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes = 
0x100201bb341a9f540000000000000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2200, 
_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=[FILTERED], 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=[FILTERED], _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, 
_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2200, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the 
server.}
```

And the Error just only happen on the IOS . And i did not find Code=-11853

my question:
1. What is the cause of this error ?
2. how to fix it ?

Thanks

Comment: Expected Result :
After unlock the device I need to continue the video where its stops.but its failed and am getting error message.If anyone knows about this problem plz help me out.